# Differentiable function check

Tags: calculus

If f(x) and g(x) are differentiable function for all $0\le x\le 23$ such that f(0)=2, g(0)=0, f(23)=22, g(23)=10, then show that f'(x)=2g'(x) for al least one x in the interval (0,23).

My approach let $f(x)=2+\frac{20}{23} x$ and $g(x)=\frac{10}{23} x$, this satisfies the condition f(0)=2, g(0)=0, f(23)=22, g(23)=10, on differentiating we get $f'(x)=\frac{20}{23}$ and $g'(x)=\frac{10}{23}$, hence $f'(x)=2g'(x)$.

Because I presumed the equation based on the value, is their any other way of doing this problem

Comment: You have to prove the statement for every functions that verify the conditions, not only for an example of them.

Comment: how can i generalize the equation based on the information provided in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

Your goal is to prove that, for every $f$ and $g$ satisfying the conditions of the statement, there exists $x \in [0, 23]$ such that $f'(x)-2g'(x) = 0$, i.e. to prove that $(f-2g)'(x)$ vanishes at a point $x \in [0, 23]$.

Now you have a very famous theorem whose conclusion is that a derivative vanishes, it's Rolle's theorem.

Can you try to apply Rolle's theorem to this situation ?

Comment: Yes i can apply Rolles theoram

Comment: Doesn't that give you the result ?

Comment: Yes i got the result